# how to work with css transition button on my website

Tags: html, css

I need to make a download button on my website like this website "www.showboxdownload.com" 
You can see the bottom right corner when you scroll down. I need to make the button similarly visible when someone scroll down and hide when scroll up. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use any [Scroll to Top](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_to_top.asp) tutorial and replace the function of the button. And maybe check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you ask your next question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will keep things in mind next time. Pardon as I am a noob

Answer (score 0):

You need listen a scroll.

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Then add a button with **id** is **myBtn** like a: `<button id="myBtn">Download</button>` with initial display is **none**.
As example you can use:

```
#myBtn {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```